# Find the sum of the series (manipulate to series first)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, power-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\inf (-1)^{n-1}\frac{3^n}{n5^n}$$ I recognize it must be one of $$e^x$$ or $$\frac1{1-x}$$ when expanded to series and must be manipulated to it but so far I made it to $$\sum_{n=1}^\inf \frac{-1}{n}(\frac{-3}{5})^n$$ any hints to next steps?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually related to the series for $\log$. Try using
$$ \log (x + 1) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} x^n
$$
and find the appropriate $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Considering $$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^n} n$$ Differentiate to get $$S'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} x^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n} x^{n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x)^{n}=\frac 1{1+x} $$ Integrating $$S=\log(1+x)$$ Replace $x$ by $\frac 35$